# itextpdf -> parse html string within a table cell

Tags: itext

trying to use itextpdf to write to PDF.
In this, trying to create a table.
In one of the table cell, i have a html content to write.
I ve searched and tried various ways but not able to write it in a proper fashion.
Any help is greatly appreciated.
Even though HtmlWorker is deprecated, tried the below and its working ok in very simple cases but not which has bullet points etc.
XMLWorkerHelper is not giving back any content to write to the table cell.

```
String htmltext="<ul><li><span style=\"text-decoration-line: underline;\">test </span></li></ul><p style=\"font-family: &quot;;;;helvetica neue&quot, helvetica, arial, sans-seriffont-size: small;\"></p>"
 java.util.List<Element> parseHtmlToList= HTMLWorker.parseToList(new StringReader(htmltext),null);
                            Paragraph valueToParagragh = new Paragraph();
                              for(Element e:parseHtmlToList){
                                 // System.out.println("Element:"+e);
                                    valueToParagragh.add(e);

                              }
                             c1 = new PdfPCell(valueToParagragh)
```

Comment: Run your HTML through the validator at https://validator.w3.org/check. Got any errors?

Comment: thanks for reply, I used a html editor and got the right result. I also used XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer,document, new StringReader(htmltext) and checked that the pdf output the bullet point. I just need to write to the cell rather than to the document.

Comment: I just need to write to the cell rather than to the document. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm facing the same situation, found any answer?